# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken returns GoogleAuthException: ServiceDisabled

Tags: android, android-studio, google-drive-android-api

I have followed the procedure mentioned in the google documentation regarding creating enabling Google Drive API and creating credentials for Google drive in the Developer Console for Google Drive. i am calling authentication as given below, accountName is the gmail ID. When I call the below function i get ServiceDisabled exception.

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, gam.getAccountByName(accountName), "oauth2:" + DriveScopes.DRIVE)
```

I have 2 different app's, one personal and other developed for a 3rd party. Since both are developed by me i have used the same JKS file for signing the apps. Since the JKS file is same SHA1 is same for both. Is that creating problem here ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue got fixed. The issue was with Oauth Consent. It is necessary to fill all the fields in the Oauth Consent, give product name, add icon, provide urls in all the below fields. If no personal URLs available then give the url of the firebase. If your app is already registered with firebase then URL of firebase should be already there and just copy and paste in all the below URL links. This solves the problem